# \and command in \author tag

Tags: titles

I have a problem with the `\and` command in an `\author` tag. My documentclass is `\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{eitExjobb}` and the .cls file can be found here: http://cl.ly/code/28202Q2P3I3g

My code:

```
\Title{Title here}
\Author{John Doe \\
    \texttt{john@email.com} 
    \and
    Jane Doe \\
    \texttt{jane@email.com}
}
\Date{\today}
\Advisor{Some Person}
\MakeTitlePage
```

And this is the error I get:

```
! Misplaced \crcr.
\endtabular ->\crcr 
                    \egroup \egroup $\egroup 
l.38 \MakeTitlePage
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the standard class the author is printed inside the environment `tabular`. Therefor the command `\and` is defined as:

```
\def\and{%                  % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
```

In your case you don't need an extra `\and`. You document class puts the author in a center environment. So you can use

```
\Author{John Doe \\
    \texttt{john@email.com} 
    %\and
    \\
    Jane Doe \\
    \texttt{jane@email.com}
}
```

Comment: This skips a line. Is it possible instead of skipping line to put both names on the same line but different sides?

Comment: @Dimme: Do you mean `\hspace*{2cm}` or `\hfill`?

Comment: It looks like \hspace*{2cm} will do the job. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Where can I find the definition of `\and` that you post here?

Answer (score 7):

In `article` class `\author` command is internally set as a tabular and `\and` finishes one tabular and starts another so a list of authors becomes a list of tabulars.

this class just sets Author in a `center` environment and doesn't provide a replacement for `\and`. You could just use `\\` or use

```
\renewcommand\and{\\[\baselineskip]}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, \\ skips line. I would like the names to be on the same line, just different sides. Is that possible? Can I change somehow the class to make that possible?

Comment: Too late :-( -- As always