# Imitate J Pol Econ titles

Tags: titles, author, affiliation

I'm trying to imitate (not exactly replicate) the titles from the Journal of Political Economy (see e.g. [the first page of this example](http://perseus.iies.su.se/%7Epkrus/ref_pub/250034.pdf)), but have starting to stumble. My problem is that I can't define separate fonts for authors and affiliations. I have posted the result of my attempts thus far using the `titling` package at the bottom of the post.

I know that I could fix this using the `authblk` package, but I would prefer not to as it [interferes with the `hyperref` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471277/hyperref-s-pdfusetitle-option-fails-with-authblk). I am in no way married to using `titling`. In fact, I think that it might actually be a better idea to redefine `\maketitle` altogether.

P.S. I am aware that it might be easier to just hardcode the title myself instead of using `\maketitle` but I would like to use this in a class eventually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titling}
\makeatletter
\pretitle{\vspace{-60\p@}\begin{flushleft}\fontsize{22pt}{24pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 5em}
\preauthor{\flushleft\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright}p{\textwidth}@{}}}
\renewcommand\and{%
  \end{tabular} \\[1em]%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright}p{\textwidth}@{}}}%
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize}
\postdate{\par\end{flushleft}}
\makeatother

\title{On the Origins of the Philosopher's Stone}
\author{Albus Dumbledore \\ Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, International Confederation of Wizards, and the Wizengamot \and Nicholas Flamel\\Beauxbatons Academy of Magic}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of result of my attempts thus far]

Comment: I found the definition of `\and` in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109658/and-command-in-author-tag) but would be very interested in finding where it is defined originally

Comment: Standard LaTeX.  See siource2e.pdf page 594-595.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I redefined `\@maketitle`. I got [help from Willie Wong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592028/split-the-author-list-at-and-without-redefining-author-or-author/592053#592053) to adjust [Ruben's answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391438/split-the-authors-list-at-and/392676#392676) and then I put some finishing touches on it.

One thing still bugs me though: perhaps there is something better than `\empty` to delimit the second argument of `\FPA@formatauthor`? Perhaps `\empty` is an outright bad choice? LaTeX is mystery to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\FPA@formatauthor#1\\#2\empty{{\LARGE\sffamily#1} \\ {\itshape#2}}% Format author affiliation pair
\def\FPA@author{}% Initialize \FPA@author
\def\split@and#1\and#2{% Populate \FPA@author recursively
  \g@addto@macro\FPA@author{\FPA@formatauthor#1\empty}
  \ifx#2\@nil\else
    \g@addto@macro\FPA@author{\par\vskip 3ex}
    \expandafter\split@and\expandafter#2\fi
}
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
  \newpage
  \let\footnote\thanks
  \expandafter\split@and\@author\and\@nil% Initialize recursion
  \flushleft
  {\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\@title\par}
  \vskip 10ex\rule[2ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}
  {\FPA@author\par}
  \vskip 2ex
  {\@date\par}}
\makeatother

\title{On the Origins of the Philosopher's Stone}
\author{Albus Dumbledore\thanks{A footnote} \\ Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, International Confederation of Wizards, and the Wizengamot \and Nicholas Flamel\\ Beauxbatons Academy of Magic}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: End result]